# How to check if my usb tvtuner is working

Tags: usb, tv-tuner

I am trying to get my USB TV tuner to show the picture from my building's security camera. The camera is set up in the lobby and is fed to my flat via an analog signal in the building's shared TV antenna connection, alongside my digital TV signal. I am able to tune into it using the TV.

I'm working on a side project for which I need to be able to grab the camera image so I researched which analog TV tuner should work with linux, and decided on a 'Pinnacle PCTV USB2' after reading this https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Pinnacle_PCTV_USB2

I have followed the guidance above and all seems to work ok - I can bring up `tvtime` and see the familiar snow of an untuned tv. I have tried to tune the device using `tvtime-scanner`, set to `PAL` (I am in the UK) but have not managed to find the signal from the security camera.

My TV is able to find the signal, using the same coax lead, and it also says that the signal is strong.

I know there are various module settings such as `options em28xx card=3 tuner=38` and `options tuner pal=b secam=b` which i have fiddled with - but i am not sure what would be the effect if they were not exactly correct, because they seem to have no effect either for better or worse when I change them. Also there are a few different `norm` options that are a variation on `PAL` - would getting these not exactly correct cause tvtime-scanner to find no signal?

Any help greatly appreciated!

nfv